# Multi File C Programs

Tags: c

I am trying to create a  multifile c program, I am using a function in one file that I want to call again from another file, how do I do this without making either of the files header files? Can I use function prototypes for this?

Comment: Why not use header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use functions defined in another file, you must use a header file, but you don't convert your .c files to header files, you include the function prototypes needed by one particular class (file) in the header file, and then include that header file in each file.

```
calc.h
calc.c <---- include calc.h

main.c <---- include calc.h
```